# Cyrillic symbols are shown as hieroglyphs, httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("")

Tags: c#, encoding

The problem is that when I am trying so send error message to front end,
it is shown as an abracadabra.

I have tried all available types of encoding from `Encoding` class.

Code example:

```
               _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                var diff1byte1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(result.ErrorMessage); 
                var diff1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(diff1byte1); 

                var diff1byte2 = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(result.ErrorMessage); 
                var diff2 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(diff1byte2); 

                var diff1byte3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.ErrorMessage); 
                var diff3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(diff1byte3); 

                var diff1byte4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(result.ErrorMessage); 
                var diff4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(diff1byte4); 

                var diff1byte5 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.ErrorMessage); 
                var diff5 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(diff1byte5); 

                var diff1byte6 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(result.ErrorMessage); 
                var diff6 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(diff1byte6); 

                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{result.ErrorMessage}");
                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{diff1}", Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);
                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{diff2}", Encoding.UTF7);
                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{diff3}", Encoding.UTF8);
                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{diff4}", Encoding.UTF32);
                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{diff5}", Encoding.ASCII);
                await _httpContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Source :{diff6}", Encoding.Unicode);
```

**Source text**:
Не найден параметр Номер заявки: 0032274764 Фильтр по станции отправления = 5863

Source :ГђВќГђВµ ГђВЅГђВ°ГђВ№ГђВґГђВµГђВЅ ГђВїГђВ°Г‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВјГђВµГ‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВќГђВѕГђВјГђВµГ‘в‚¬ ГђВ·ГђВ°Г‘ВЏГђВІГђВєГђВё: 0032274764 ГђВ¤ГђВёГђВ»Г‘Е’Г‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВїГђВѕ Г‘ВЃГ‘вЂљГђВ°ГђВЅГ‘вЂ ГђВёГђВё ГђВѕГ‘вЂљГђВїГ‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВІГђВ»ГђВµГђВЅГђВёГ‘ВЏ = 5863

Source :ГђВќГђВµ ГђВЅГђВ°ГђВ№ГђВґГђВµГђВЅ ГђВїГђВ°Г‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВјГђВµГ‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВќГђВѕГђВјГђВµГ‘в‚¬ ГђВ·ГђВ°Г‘ВЏГђВІГђВєГђВё: 0032274764 ГђВ¤ГђВёГђВ»Г‘Е’Г‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВїГђВѕ Г‘ВЃГ‘вЂљГђВ°ГђВЅГ‘вЂ ГђВёГђВё ГђВѕГ‘вЂљГђВїГ‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВІГђВ»ГђВµГђВЅГђВёГ‘ВЏ = 5863

Source :ГђВќГђВµ ГђВЅГђВ°ГђВ№ГђВґГђВµГђВЅ ГђВїГђВ°Г‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВјГђВµГ‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВќГђВѕГђВјГђВµГ‘в‚¬ ГђВ·ГђВ°Г‘ВЏГђВІГђВєГђВё: 0032274764 ГђВ¤ГђВёГђВ»Г‘Е’Г‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВїГђВѕ Г‘ВЃГ‘вЂљГђВ°ГђВЅГ‘вЂ ГђВёГђВё ГђВѕГ‘вЂљГђВїГ‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВІГђВ»ГђВµГђВЅГђВёГ‘ВЏ = 5863

Source :ГђВќГђВµ ГђВЅГђВ°ГђВ№ГђВґГђВµГђВЅ ГђВїГђВ°Г‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВјГђВµГ‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВќГђВѕГђВјГђВµГ‘в‚¬ ГђВ·ГђВ°Г‘ВЏГђВІГђВєГђВё: 0032274764 ГђВ¤ГђВёГђВ»Г‘Е’Г‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВїГђВѕ Г‘ВЃГ‘вЂљГђВ°ГђВЅГ‘вЂ ГђВёГђВё ГђВѕГ‘вЂљГђВїГ‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВІГђВ»ГђВµГђВЅГђВёГ‘ВЏ = 5863

Source :ГђВќГђВµ ГђВЅГђВ°ГђВ№ГђВґГђВµГђВЅ ГђВїГђВ°Г‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВјГђВµГ‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВќГђВѕГђВјГђВµГ‘в‚¬ ГђВ·ГђВ°Г‘ВЏГђВІГђВєГђВё: 0032274764 ГђВ¤ГђВёГђВ»Г‘Е’Г‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВїГђВѕ Г‘ВЃГ‘вЂљГђВ°ГђВЅГ‘вЂ ГђВёГђВё ГђВѕГ‘вЂљГђВїГ‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВІГђВ»ГђВµГђВЅГђВёГ‘ВЏ = 5863

Source :?? ?????? ???????? ????? ??????: 0032274764 ?????? ?? ??????? ??????????? = 5863

Source :ГђВќГђВµ ГђВЅГђВ°ГђВ№ГђВґГђВµГђВЅ ГђВїГђВ°Г‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВјГђВµГ‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВќГђВѕГђВјГђВµГ‘в‚¬ ГђВ·ГђВ°Г‘ВЏГђВІГђВєГђВё: 0032274764 ГђВ¤ГђВёГђВ»Г‘Е’Г‘вЂљГ‘в‚¬ ГђВїГђВѕ Г‘ВЃГ‘вЂљГђВ°ГђВЅГ‘вЂ ГђВёГђВё ГђВѕГ‘вЂљГђВїГ‘в‚¬ГђВ°ГђВІГђВ»ГђВµГђВЅГђВёГ‘ВЏ = 5863

Could anybody please suggest, how to resolve this problem ?

**Update**

Debug:

[image]

Browser console output:

[image]

Comment: Which kind of app do you have, .NET Core or classic .NET?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski .NET core

Comment: What is the actual value `result.ErrorMessage`, does it equal to source text? Because it works with utf8 encoding. Where did you see a wrong text, on a client side?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski please check the update section

Comment: It is russian which requires windows-1251 encoding :            string input = "Не найден параметр Номер заявки: 0032274764 Фильтр по станции отправления";
            byte[] output = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetBytes(input);